# Radio Buttons in android

Tags: java

I have a problem with my radio buttons.I need to have two of the same such as "male" and "female". Problem is that both of them can be checked at the same time and furthermore they can't be unchecked.Please help my help is down below

```
    // Implement necessary constructors
    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(isChecked()) {
            if(getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup)getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            setChecked(true);
        }
  }
```

Comment: did you add them to a group?

Comment: Yes so that when one is checked the other can't be checked without unchecking the first